# Setting a Workflow variable as a long date

Tags: date-time, workflow-variable

I have seen all the suggestions for extracting the day of the week from a long date in a SP workflow.  I would love to be able to set my date/time variable to a long date but the system will not let me.  What is the problem?

[image: Variable I am trying to create as long date]

Comment: Sorry I am missing the bigger picture. Once you have a date time object can't you just format it in the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

Like Amal said you can just change how it appears in your form. I would suggest making custom forms to do this. You can find date formats here: [Custom date formats.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/)
Unless I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

make that workflow variable as string data type.  You can able to access those dropdown values